# How to re-ask declined permissions using parse.facebookutils.login in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, parsefacebookutils

How to re-ask declined permissions using `parse.facebookutils.login`

```
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('public_profile,email', {
   success: function(user) 
   {

   },
   error: function(error) 
   {
       console.log(error); 
       console.log("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
   }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I fixed the title and updated tags, so more people with knowledge of the subject will see it. I also fixed minor formatting issues to improve readability.  Please edit in the more details like the context where you are using this. Good luck!

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#users-additional-permissions

Were you able to just re-ask for permissions with the login dialog and if so did that work for you?